# How do I create a select statement to return distinct values, column name and table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, concatenation

I would like to create a SQL Statement that will return the  distinct values of the Code fields in my database, along with the name of the column for the codes and the name of the table on which the column occurs.

I had something like this:

```
select c.name as 'Col Name', t.name as "Table Name'
from sys.columns c, sys tables t
where c.object_id = t.object_id
and c.name like 'CD_%'
```

It generates the list of columns and tables I want, but obviously doesn't return any of the values for each of the codes in the list.

There are over 100 tables in my database. I could use the above result set and write the query for each one like this:

```
Select distinct CD_RACE from PERSON
```

and it will return the values, but it won't return the column and table name, plus I have to do each one individually. Is there any way I can get the value, column name and table name for EACH code in my database?

Any ideas? THanks...

Comment: What do you mean by how `can i get the value, column name and table name for EACH code in my database?` Do you want to get the [DDL-Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) or the values / the [records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)) in each table?

Comment: By value I mean, we have values 1, 2, 3, 4 5, 6 and 7 in CD_RACE. I want a result that shows 1 CD_RACE PERSON in the first row, 2 CD_RACE PERSON in the second row and so on... The answer below I believe just generates the column and table name, but won't give the actual VALUE of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate your selects and bring in the column and table names as static values. Here's an Oracle version:

select 'select distinct '''||c.column_name||''' as "Col Name", '''||t.table_name||''' as "Table Name", '||c.column_name||' from '||t.table_name||';'
from all_tab_columns c, all_tables t
where c.table_name = t.table_name;

This will give you a bunch of separate statements, you can modify the query a bit to put a union between each select if you really want one uber query you can execute to get all your code values at once.

Comment: I am in a SQL Server 2012 environment. If I do the above, will the first column be the literal name of the column and the third column be the actual value?

Comment: This query will actually generate a set of queries for you, to pull the column name, table name, value from all the tables you want to pull these values from. So, you would take the result of this query and execute it to get your actual list of column/table/value. This is a quick and dirty solution (I assumed this was a one-off), Jason's answer is a better solution if this is something you're going to need to do on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach for SQL Server since someone else covered Oracle (and specific DBMS not mentioned. The following steps are completed:

1. Setup table to receive the schema, table, column name, and column value (in example below only table variable is used)
2. Build the list of SQL commands to execute (accounting for various schemas and names with spaces and such)
3. Run each command dynamically inserting values into the setup table from #1 above
4. Output results from table

Here is the example:

```
-- Store the values and source of the values
DECLARE @Values TABLE (
    SchemaName VARCHAR(500),
    TableName VARCHAR(500),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(500),
    ColumnValue VARCHAR(MAX)
)

-- Build list of SQL Commands to run
DECLARE @Commands TABLE (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    SchemaName VARCHAR(500),
    TableName VARCHAR(500),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(500),
    SqlCommand VARCHAR(1000)
)
INSERT @Commands
    SELECT
        [TABLE_SCHEMA],
        [TABLE_NAME],
        [COLUMN_NAME],
        'SELECT DISTINCT '
            + '''' + [TABLE_SCHEMA] + ''', '
            + '''' + [TABLE_NAME] + ''', '
            + '''' + [COLUMN_NAME] + ''', '
            + '[' + [COLUMN_NAME] + '] '
            + 'FROM [' + [TABLE_SCHEMA] + '].[' + [TABLE_NAME] + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'CD_%'

-- Loop through commands
DECLARE
    @Sql VARCHAR(1000),
    @Id INT,
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(500),
    @TableName VARCHAR(500),
    @ColumnName VARCHAR(500)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Commands) BEGIN
    -- Get next set of records
    SELECT TOP 1
        @Id = Id,
        @Sql = SqlCommand,
        @SchemaName = SchemaName,
        @TableName = TableName,
        @ColumnName = ColumnName
    FROM @Commands

    -- Add values for that command
    INSERT @Values
        EXEC (@Sql)

    -- Remove command record
    DELETE @Commands WHERE Id = @Id
END

-- Return the values and sources
SELECT * FROM @Values
```

Comment: @sqluser2014 Please feel free to upvote an answer if it helped you and accept it if it solved your question. This helps others to know which answers may have helped with your question. It also increases your reputation.